# Comunication between Location-based game and PHP REST webservice

Tags: c#, php, mysql, rest, unity-game-engine

I'm making a PokemonGo-like game.
Simply, each player chooses which faction to belong (indicated by three different colors); The main purpose of the game is to capture the towers that the server creates close to the player's geographical position.
Much of what I've described above has already been implemented and almost functional, but I have many doubts about the database and communication with it. I have currently written a REST web service in php that allows me to check if the players are registered and if they are online. Basically, in the player client in Unity I created a simple login interface where, after writing username and password, these data are inserted into a WWWForm object and the following call, UnityWebRequest.Post (loginUrl, form) , I can understand if the data entered corresponds to a registered user or not.

```cs
    LoginStatus logInStatus = new LoginStatus();
    var form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("username",id); //id,pass = textField
    form.AddField("password",pass);
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(loginUrl, form))
    {
        yield return www.Send();
        if (www.isNetworkError)
            gui.activatePopUp("Connection error, retry!");
        else
        {
            var postResponse = www.downloadHandler.text;
            gui.activatePopUp(logInStatus.getMessage(postResponse));
            if (logInStatus.Success)
            {
                infos.username = id;
                infos.password = pass;
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("ClientScene");
            }
        }
    }
```

The loginUrl is a string variable that contains the login REST service address. So far, it's all simple and acceptable. The problem is that in the future I will need to retrieve much more information from the database, ie a player will be represented, for example, by the attributes Username, Faction, Level and so on. so what is the most appropriate way to intelligently communicate such an application with a web service rest? How do I make a smart mapping between my business classes and the relational model? Currently, the REST service queries a remote MySQL database.
Can some ORM be used?

A first solution I thought about is to apply the DAO pattern, let me return the records from the database as JSON and use a parser that recreates the objects. Do you think it's smart enough and efficient as a solution?